# Can I release ivar in an instance method of the same class? (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

Can I release ivar in an instance method of the same class? Because I want to alloc-init it again. Does this conflict with the other `[_myNSStringIvar release];` in `-(void)dealloc`?

```
    // in the middle of an instance method
    if(_myNSStringIvar != nil){
        [_myNSStringIvar release];
    }

    _myNSStringIvar = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:(NSString *)[aDictionary objectForKey:@"key"]];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can release whenever you don't need the referenced object anymore. You don't even have to check for `nil` before releasing, as you can just send `release` to `nil`.

```
[_myNSStringIvar release];
_myNSStringIvar = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:(NSString *)[aDictionary objectForKey:@"key"]];
```

You also don't have to `alloc] init]` a new string object, instead copy the existing object:

```
[_myNSStringIvar release];
_myNSStringIvar = [aDictionary[@"key"] copy];
```

That way, you only retain if `aDictionary[@"key"]` is immutable, and copy if it is a `NSMutableString` object.

Now if you use a property with the `copy` attribute, you don't even have to manually `release`:

```
@property (copy) NSString *myNSString;
...
self.myNSString = aDictionary[@"key"];
```

The old object is released in the setter, the new one will be copied.